# Load JSON to Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can i load a json string into a Spark Dataframe using python

Example:

```
sampleJson = [
 ('{"user":1, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]}',), 
 ('{"user":2, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]}',), 
 ('{"user":3, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]}',), 
 ('{"user":4, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]}',), 
 ('{"user":5, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]}',), 
 ('{"user":6, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]}',), 
]
```

What would be the best way to load it into a dataframe with schema

```
user - int 
IP - String
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: You want to put each IP on a separate row?

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica - Yes, 1 row should have 1 IP. User 1 will be repeated 4 times, once for evbery IP

Answer (score 0):

{

```
package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, col}

object LoadJsonToDataFrame extends App {


  val sampleJson = """[
                     |  {"user":1, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]},
                     |  {"user":2, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]},
                     |  {"user":3, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]},
                     |  {"user":4, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]},
                     |  {"user":5, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]},
                     |  {"user":6, "IP" :["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3", "10.0.0.4"]}
                     |]""".stripMargin


  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(sampleJson)).toDF("value")
  df1.show(false)
  val rdd = df1.rdd.map(_.getString(0))

  val ds = rdd.toDS
  val df = spark.read.json(ds)

  df.show(false)
//  +----------------------------------------+----+
//  |IP                                      |user|
//  +----------------------------------------+----+
//  |[10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.4]|1   |
//  |[10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.4]|2   |
//  |[10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.4]|3   |
//  |[10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.4]|4   |
//  |[10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.4]|5   |
//  |[10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.4]|6   |
//  +----------------------------------------+----+
  df.printSchema()
//  root
//  |-- IP: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
//  |-- user: long (nullable = true)

 // explode
      val explodeDF = df
        .withColumn("ipExplode", explode(col("IP")))
          .select('user, 'ipExplode)

      explodeDF.show(50, false)
//      +----+---------+
//      |user|ipExplode|
//      +----+---------+
//      |1   |10.0.0.1 |
//      |1   |10.0.0.2 |
//      |1   |10.0.0.3 |
//      |1   |10.0.0.4 |
//      |2   |10.0.0.1 |
//      |2   |10.0.0.2 |
//      |2   |10.0.0.3 |
//      |2   |10.0.0.4 |
//      |3   |10.0.0.1 |
//      |3   |10.0.0.2 |
//      |3   |10.0.0.3 |
//      |3   |10.0.0.4 |
//      |4   |10.0.0.1 |
//      |4   |10.0.0.2 |
//      |4   |10.0.0.3 |
//      |4   |10.0.0.4 |
//      |5   |10.0.0.1 |
//      |5   |10.0.0.2 |
//      |5   |10.0.0.3 |
//      |5   |10.0.0.4 |
//      |6   |10.0.0.1 |
//      |6   |10.0.0.2 |
//      |6   |10.0.0.3 |
//      |6   |10.0.0.4 |
//      +----+---------+

}
```

}

Comment: Can it be pivoted to have 1 IP per row. Each user will be repeated 4 times, once for every IP.

Comment: added example with explode to my answer.